# Liferay 7.1 : Import Material Design Bootstrap in my liferay theme

Tags: bootstrap-4, material-design, liferay, liferay-7, liferay-theme

I've generated a liferay theme in 7.1 with liferay generator. All works.

Now I want to add Material Design Bootstrap in my theme (https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/). And i got this : 
[image]

How could I do the integration in my liferay theme because I'm stuck ?

Thanks,

Comment: It's very hard to do it... you will find many conflitcs with liferay BS customization....

Comment: Daniele is correct. You can do it.. But I would start using the scss [from github](https://github.com/mdbootstrap/bootstrap-material-design) instead of the css files you downloaded.